# Finding the longest non-repeating element of an array, then returning its original value

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, while-loop, lodash

I am meant to find the longest unique string (non-repeating alphabets) from an array then return its original value.

So for example in the dataset below

```
3          # Number of test cases
3          # Test case 1 has 3 names
ALFRED
SINGHHHHHH
JOHN
6          # Test case 2 has 6 names
ALPHA
NITRO
ROB
RICHARD
ANON
POPE
1          # Test case 3 has 1 name
FELIX
```

Alfred, Richard and felix have the 'longest unique' name.

My problem is that my code returns the unique values instead of the original values which are needed.

So:

**Expectation Output**

```
Case #1: ALFRED
Case #2: RICHARD
Case #3: FELIX
```

**Reality**

```
Case #1: ALFRED
Case #2: RICHAD # Notice the extra R has been removed
Case #3: FELIX
```

here is the code snippet i am using:

```js
var _ = require('lodash')
var example = '3\n3\nALFRED\nSINGHHHHH\nJOHN\n6\nALPHA\nNITRO\nROB\nRICHARD\nANON\nPOPE\n1\nFELIX';


run(example)
function run(input) {
    var lines = input.split('\n')
    var testCases = lines.shift();
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < testCases; i++) {
        var testCase = obj[i + 1] = [];
        var numberOfNames = lines.shift();
        for (var j = 0; j < numberOfNames; j += 1) {
            let candidateNames = lines.shift()
            let strippedNames = _.uniq(candidateNames).join('')
            testCase.push(strippedNames)
        }
    }
    for (var k = 0; k < testCases; k++) {
        console.log(`Case #${[k + 1]}: ${findLongestName(obj[k + 1])}`)
        
    }
}

function findLongestName(str) {
  var longestWord = str.reduce(function(longest, currentWord) {
    return currentWord.length > longest.length ? currentWord : longest;
  }, '');
  return longestWord;
}
```

**EDIT**

So in some cases we may get more than 1 values which satisfy our condition of being the longest unique ones(they are all of the same length). In this case we need to select the one which appears 1st alphabetically!

eg:

```
3          # Number of test cases
3          # Test case 1 has 3 names
CKLGNTVKPJUQVHFKOJYC
ZSQXRMZYDOAICOQHPYHU
JOHN
6          # Test case 2 has 6 names
ALPHA
NITRO
ROB
RICHARD
ANON
POPE
1          # Test case 3 has 1 name
FELIX
```

In the example above `'CKLGNTVKPJUQVHFKOJYC'` should be the one selected.

Comment: What if there is two strings that have the same length? Do you want to return both?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrirsee edit above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution below uses [times](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#times) to iterate and return each of the longest non-repeating string of each test case. Its callback function uses the `lines` array (obtained from splitting the input string by `\n`) to get all strings in each case through [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). After splicing, we sort each string by their unique length (non-repeating characters in a string) using [sortBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy). Lastly, we get the [last](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#last) string in the array.

```
function getResult(input) {
  var lines = input.split('\n');
  return _.times(lines.shift(), () => {
    return _(lines)
      .splice(0, lines.shift())
      .sortBy(item => _(item).uniq().size())
      .last();
  });
}
```

```js
var input = '3\n3\nALFRED\nSINGHHHHH\nJOHN\n6\nALPHA\nNITRO\nROB\nRICHARD\nANON\nPOPE\n1\nFELIX';

function getResult(input) {
  var lines = input.split('\n');
  return _.times(lines.shift(), () => {
    return _(lines)
      .splice(0, lines.shift())
      .sortBy(item => _(item).uniq().size())
      .last();
  });
}

console.log(getResult(input));
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE:** In case of equal uniqueness, we can use [map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) to transform each item into an array composition of `[<unique length>, <string>]`, use this composition to [order](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#orderBy) each item by their unique length (index 0) in ascending order and its respective string (index 1) in descending order. Lastly, we use `map` again to get all strings (index 1).

```
function getResult(input) {
  var lines = input.split('\n');
  return _.times(lines.shift(), () => {
    return _(lines)
      .splice(0, lines.shift())
      .map(item => [_(item).uniq().size(), item])
      .orderBy([0, 1], ['asc', 'desc'])
      .map(1)
      .last();
  });
}
```

Note: I added `ALBERT`, `CKLGNTVKPJUQVHFKOJYC` and `ZSQXRMZYDOAICOQHPYHU`.

```js
var input = '3\n6\nCKLGNTVKPJUQVHFKOJYC\nZSQXRMZYDOAICOQHPYHU\nALFRED\nALBERT\nSINGHHHHH\nJOHN\n6\nALPHA\nNITRO\nROB\nRICHARD\nANON\nPOPE\n1\nFELIX';

function getResult(input) {
  var lines = input.split('\n');
  return _.times(lines.shift(), () => {
    return _(lines)
      .splice(0, lines.shift())
      .map(item => [_(item).uniq().size(), item])
      .orderBy([0, 1], ['asc', 'desc'])
      .map(1)
      .last();
  });
}

console.log(getResult(input));
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is a good solution! However in certain situations you may get strings with equal uniqueness, in that case it is meant to be sorted by alphabetical order. i though the sort by is meant to do that. You can use 'CKLGNTVKPJUQVHFKOJYC' and 'ZSQXRMZYDOAICOQHPYHU' as test cases, even though the 'CK....' is meant to appear first, it doesn't.

Comment: Added example names in comment above

Comment: @KCM So in that case, it should return `'ZSQXRMZYDOAICOQHPYHU'`?

Comment: No, it should return `CKLGNTVKPJUQVHFKOJYC`, since we want it alphabetically

Comment: Ok, this  sorts alphabetically but now it breaks the original idea of getting the longest one. So incase you add `'CKLGNTVKPJUQVHFKOJYC'` to the list you will notice it gets ignored. Ill update the question too. basically we check for the longest unique name, if there are more than 1 then we select the 1st one whose 1st chracter appears alphabetically.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I think the problem is the way I remove the repeating characters, let me update it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136739/discussion-between-kc-m-and-ryeballar).

Comment: I think we need to define the term `non-repeating` in this context. Does it mean `non-repeating` in a consecutive manner? or as a whole? e.g. `ALPHA` - Does this word have a unique length of 4 or 5?

Comment: `ALPHA` has 4 in such a case

Answer (score 1):

```js
function run(input) {
  var lines = input.split('\n');
  var testCases = lines.shift();
  var result = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < testCases; i++) {
    var hash = {};                                  // an hash object for the lengths of this test case (see explanation bellow)
    var numberOfNames = lines.shift();              // the number of names in this test case
    for (var j = 0; j < numberOfNames; j += 1) {    // for each name in this test case
      let name = lines.shift();                     // get the name
      let length = _.uniq(name).length;             // get its unique length (the length of its unique characters)
      if (hash[length])                             // if we laready hashed this length
        hash[length].push(name);                    // then push this original name to the according array
      else                                          // if we haven't
        hash[length] = [name];                      // then create a new array for this length (initially containing this name)
    }
    //console.log(hash);
    var max = Math.max.apply(null, Object.keys(hash)); // get the max length from the hash object (the lengths are the keys of the hash object)
    //console.log(max);
    result["Test Case " + (i + 1)] = hash[max];     // store the array for that length as the result of this test case
  }
  return result;
}

var example = '3\n3\nALFRED\nSINGHHHHH\nJOHN\n6\nALPHA\nNITRO\nROB\nRICHARD\nANON\nPOPE\n1\nFELIX';

var result = run(example);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

**Explanation:**

For example, if the use case is:

```
ALFRED
SINGHHHHHH
JOHN
BANANA
```

for each name in the test case, we get the length of its unique characters (the lengths in the example above will be `6`, `5`, `4` and `6` respectively). Then we store the names that have the same length into an array and store that array into the hash object under a key which is the length, so the hash object for the above example will look like:

```
hash = {
  6: ["ALFRED", "BANANA"],
  5: ["SINGHHHHHH"],
  4: ["JOHN"]
}
```

then we get the maximum length among the keys of the array (`6` in the example) and we then store the equivalent array (`["ALFRED", "BANANA"]`) as the result for this test case.

**EDIT:**

If you want to choose only the first one that appeared, then change this line:

```
result["Test Case " + (i + 1)] = hash[max];    // instead of pushing the whole array
```

to:

```
result["Test Case " + (i + 1)] = hash[max][0]; // just push the first item of that array
//                                        ^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very friendly data structure but still you may functionally do as follows;

```js
function doSomething(s){
  return s.split("\n")
          .slice(1) // throw away the useless first information
          .reduce((r,c,i,a) => Number.isInteger(+c) ? (r.push(a.slice(i+1,+c+i+1)),r) : r, [])
          .map(g => g.map(s => Array.prototype.reduce.call(s, function(r,c){
                                                                c === r[r.length-1] && (r.stop = true);
                                                                !r.stop && r.push(c);
                                                                return r;
                                                              },[])
                                              .join(""))
                     .reduce((p,c) => p.length > c.length ? p : c));
}
var data = '3\n3\nALFRED\nSINGHHHHH\nJOHN\n6\nALPHA\nNITRO\nROB\nRICHARD\nANON\nPOPE\n1\nFELIX';

console.log(doSomething(data));
```